# Restrict entries in SharePoint view

Tags: list, list-view

I have created a custom list in Sharepoint 2010 with below columns.

```
Name(Single line of text)
Location(Single line of text)
Manager(Single line of text)
Joining(Radio button with Yes/No values)
```

In the default view created, I can see all the rows that have been entered. I want to display only those entries that have value "yes" in Joining column.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is modify the default view (either by going to the list settings, scrolling down, and clicking on All Items; or by clicking on List under the List Tools header in the ribbon and selecting Modify view).

Within modify view there is a Filter section where you can choose the column Joining, leave it as 'is equal to' and write in Yes as the value there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to know one more thing. I have another column "comments" that is multiple line of text type. I want to select all the entries that have value in comments column but SharePoint does not allow me to use this field with "is equal to" or "is not equal to".

Comment: Unfortunately, to do so you would need to either use sharepoint designer and convert it to a data view or do something 'hackish' like doing a contains for a, e, i, o, u, or y, which should return any valid comment